# ajax response get returned, but sometimes doesn't trigger any actions or alerts

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a fairly standard ajax request, and the response is returned as an array. 
It works perfectly 90% of the time.

Unfortunately 10% of the time, the request gets sent, response get's returned, but doesn't get displayed, and I can't even output to an alert.

Firebug shows no errors with the response. I can open the response in another window and it is fine. I've gone through the response and don't see any obvious encoding errors. Though things like st.paul's are coming out as

```
st.paul\x92S.
```

The data being returned is being retrieved from a csv file which was translated to csv from an excel file.

it always fails on the same requests. So 90% of the requests go through fine, 10% will fail with no errors, but it is always the same 10%.

I'm using rails, and the output is generated by

```
render ({:content_type => :js, :text => @col_data.uniq})
```

I get the csv like this, and strip out leading and trailing whitespace. Maybe I should be looking to strip or encode other characters?

```
    def csv_data
        csv=Dataset.find(session[:dataset_id])
        @csv_data = CSV.read(csv.dataset.path)
        @csv_data = @csv_data.each{|row| row.each {|col|col.to_s.strip!}}
        return @csv_data
    end
```

I'd include the output here, but it is a long array, and I've gone through it looking for nil, or character encodings, but the encodings that exist are definitely escaped.

This question was originally posted as an ajax response size error because that is the obvious difference I saw between what worked, and what didn't work, but the initial comments lead me to believe that size isn't the issue as the large responses are under 45kb.

The jquery ajax code is pretty straightforward. I've tried both with dataType: 'json', and without setting a dataType. 
The 'alert' is triggered when the data is returned, however, in these situations where the data is not returned, the alert is not triggered. Yet, I can see the output in firebug, so their is a non-error response.

```
var selected_field=jQuery('option:selected',this).text();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'selectfilter',
        data: 'column_name='+selected_field,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
                        alert(data.toSource());
            if(data.length==0){
            alert('the selected column has no data');
            }
            var list='';

            for (var i=0;i'+data[i]+'';
            }

            jQuery('table#sample_data').html(list).data('list',data);
            }
                  })
```

Comment: I don't think 40kb on an ajax response will max it out. I think you're problem lies somewhere else. What makes you think it has a file size limit?

Comment: What kind of effects do you see? Does the request break?

Comment: Have to go with 40kb size not being an issue - i have Ajax responses that regularly top 5 Mb in size (then Browser timeout issues do become a problem - generally solve these by putting the requested function off to spawn and then use a client side javascript call to check to see if the temporary file has finished being written to).

Comment: @Pasted & @Dominic - I thought the 40kb was the size limit because I'm not getting any errors, and the only time I can't output anything is when the responses I'm returning are larger than the others that return fine. A few other searches lead me to believe that the size limit might be what is breaking it. Could be character encoding, I'll edit the post.

Comment: @ploarblau - I see no 'effects' which is what is making this so difficult to debug. The request does not break, Firebug shows it returns the array.  Firebug shows no errors, trying to alert anything in the 'success' doesn't get triggered, and when I open the page via the the firebug request, the content of the page looks fine. I'm updating the question as it sounds like this isn't related to file size limit.

Comment: Can you post your jQuery part or how you make your ajax request?

Comment: Did you try using 'error' attribute in your Ajax call? And can you specify your jquery version?

Comment: Have you tried rendering your data in your controller differently, like with a "render :json => @col_data.uniq"?

Comment: @Shaked KO, I used the error function as you suggested, but the response is 200 OK.

Comment: @plang - I have tried different formats for the render, but I had always been using render :content_type. From my initial testing, it seems your solution solved the problem. More testing to do, but please include it as an answer so I can accept it (assuming further testing proves that this is the correct answer). At minimum, it may help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried rendering your data in your controller differently, like with a "render :json => @col_data.uniq"?

Comment: absolutely amazed that it was something this simple, and really quite unrelated to any direction I was headed with debugging. Hopefully this saves somebody the many, many hours I spent trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hi @pedalpete, I'm pretty new to stackoverflow reputation system, and more interested in helping than getting points, but how do I earn the bounty for my answer?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought when I accepted an answer it would automatically give you the points. I'm new to the bounty thing myself.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the same 10% of data is causing this problem. Do you notice any patterns in these entries? Do you have access to the data, and did you create the data?

Many times in my job, I have exported a field-updated customer database from Excel to CSV, there have been a host of extra characters that throw errors in JavaScript. `st.paul\x92S.` looks like a prime candidate, as the \x92 is unicode for the typographer single quote, or in HTML `&rsquo;`

I would suggest trying to clean the data by changing or removing the "smart quotes". Also, look to see if there are any other extra characters in your fields. One particular annoying character that is nearly impossible to notice in Excel is a carriage return (or new-line) character. Viewing the data in a text editor might help significantly.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I suspected it was an encoding error, but didn't notice anything in the output that would cause a total meltdown (as I mentioned, the outputs are quite large. However, I don't have access to the csv's, they are uploaded by the user, so I can't expect them to 'clean' the data before uploading. Is their a regex or something I could run against the csv at import to clean-up the character that would be causing this to break?